# Value not being passed to component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to put the values of an Array into a `Dropdown` component which is inside of a `Table` component to mimic a cell and I am not able to pass the value `tags` into the `Dropdown` component.

My code looks like this. Console logging Tags 2 shows `undefined`. Can anyone let me know what i'm doing wrong? I'm using ant-d w/ React

```
title: "Tags",
dataIndex: "tags",
key: "tags",
width: "10%",
render: tags => {
  {
    console.log("Tags 1", tags);
  }
  return (
    <Dropdown
      overlay={tags => {
        {
          console.log("Tags 2", tags);
        }
        return (
          <Menu>
            {tags.forEach(tag => {
              {
                console.log("Tags 3", tag);
              }
              return (
                <Menu.Item>
                  <a
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    href="http://www.taobao.com/">
                    {console.log(tag)}
                  </a>
                </Menu.Item>
              );
            })}
          </Menu>
        );
      }}>
      <a className="ant-dropdown-link">Hover me</a>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}
```

Comment: try to replace tags.forEach with tags.map

Comment: Tags isn't being passed to Tags 3, Tags 2 is coming undefined.

Comment: You're overwriting the variable `tags`. Your render has `tags` as an argument, but the Dropdown's overlay also has `tags` as an argument, so that one is overwriting the first one. Change the overlay to this: `overlay={somethingElse => console.log("Tags 2", tags}...`

Comment: Oh Yes! Didn't see that one coming. Changed it now. Thanks!